# Why doesn't f-string formatting work for Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, f-string

Given a DataFrame with `Product Id` and `Amount`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['504145', 12000.0],
                   ['555933', 23010.5]],
                  columns=['Product Id', 'Amount'])
df
Out[1]: 
  Product Id   Amount
0     504145  12000.0
1     555933  23010.5
```

I want to add a "Description" column based on `Amount`, which is expected to look like:

```py
  Product Id   Amount        Description
0     504145  12000.0  Amount is 12000.0
1     555933  23010.5  Amount is 23010.5
```

When I use f-strings formatting, the result is aggregating the whole column `Amount` as a series instead of using the value of a particular row for string concatenation:

```py
df['Description'] = f'Amount is {df["Amount"].astype(str)}'
df
Out[2]: 
  Product Id   Amount                                        Description
0     504145  12000.0  Amount is 0    12000.0\n1    23010.5\nName: Am...
1     555933  23010.5  Amount is 0    12000.0\n1    23010.5\nName: Am...
```

However, it works fine with simple string concatenation using `+`:

```py
df['Description'] = "Amount is " + df["Amount"].astype(str)
df
Out[9]: 
  Product Id   Amount        Description
0     504145  12000.0  Amount is 12000.0
1     555933  23010.5  Amount is 23010.5
```

Why does f-strings formatting in a Pandas DataFrame behave like that? How should I fix it to use f-strings formatting? Or is it not suggested to use f-strings formatting for string concatenation in Pandas?

Comment: i would really love this to work as well.  quite annoying

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need iterate by each value, e.g. by `apply`:

```
df['Description'] = df["Amount"].apply(lambda x: f'Amount is {x}')
```

Or by list comprehension:

```
df['Description'] = [f'Amount is {x}' for x in df["Amount"]]

print (df)

  Product Id   Amount        Description
0     504145  12000.0  Amount is 12000.0
1     555933  23010.5  Amount is 23010.5
```

Your solution:

```
df['Description'] = f'Amount is {df["Amount"].astype(str)}'
```

working different - it append each value of Series (also with index) to strings and repeat like constant for all values of new column.

Comment: thanks, how about if there are more columns to concat? e.g. `f'Amount for {df["Product Id"]} is {df["Amount"].astype(str)}'`

Comment: @henrywongkk - then use `df['Description'] = df.apply(lambda x: f'Amount for {x["Product Id"]} is {x["Amount"]}', axis=1)`

Comment: @henrywongkk - or `df['Description'] = [f'Amount for {a} is {b}' for a, b in zip(df["Product Id"], df["Amount"])]`

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be to use `agg` and `format`:

```
df['description'] = df.agg('Amount is {0[Amount]}'.format, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does f-strings formatting in a Pandas DataFrame behave like that?

That's just how it works: an f-string results in **a** string, not a series of strings.

The difference with `+` however, is that `+` defers to its operands, so the `Series` can go, "OK, I'm going to apply this operation to my **contents**, not to myself."