# Pandas: is pd.assign ever the right alternative to pd.apply? Seems not

Tags: pandas

I have a very wide dataframe with a `units` column that I'd like to update thusly:

```
df_historic.loc[df_historic.variable == 'Emissions Intensities'].assign(units = lambda x: f"t CO2/({x.units})")
```

But that doesn't work because x.units in this context is interpreted as a whole goddamn Series (with index decorations), and not as the iterative thing I want it to be.

pd.apply works as I wish:

```
df_historic.loc[df_historic.variable == 'Emissions Intensities', 'units'] = df_historic.loc[df_historic.variable == 'Emissions Intensities'].apply(lambda x: f"t CO2/({x.units})", axis=1)
```

But OMG is that ugly!  What syntactic sugar do I need to add to make  pd.assign work as I expect?

Comment: This answer helps with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602185/1291237, but the question remains, why doesn't assign iterate the way apply does?

Comment: Look at the documentation for assign, you are assigning to a new or existing column. Apply offers flexibility and is not limited to assignment

Comment: Correct, I am using assign to overwrite an existing column, which it is documented to do.  The flexibility of apply comes at the cost of greatly overstating in code what I'm trying to do.  Assign seems like it could do the job, but something is wrong with my understanding and/or its implementation concept.